# Calling lifecycle template methods in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In the sample code below I created a custom component which uses some lifecycle callback methods like onRender

```
Ext.onReady (function() {
Ext.define("Person", {
    extend: "Ext.Component",

    constructor: function (config) {
        this.initConfig(config),
        this.callParent();
        console.log("inside constructor");
        return this
    },

    onRender: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        console.log("inside onRender");
    },
});

Ext.create('Person', {
    width:200, 
    height:300,
    html: "hello world",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

});

Output: "inside constructor"

Looks like the lifecycle methods onRender is not called. Also "hello world" is not rendered.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know what exactly the answer.. but i try to answer it, please correct me if i wrong..

as far as i know, `callparent()` is used for call a function in its parent, that function could need parameter to pass and in this case **constructor** need a array to pass...

```
Ext.onReady (function() {
    Ext.define("Person", {
        extend: "Ext.Component",

        constructor: function (config) {
            //this.initConfig(config),
            this.callParent([config]);
            console.log("inside constructor");
            //return this
        },

        onRender: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            console.log("inside onRender");
        },
    });

    Ext.create('Person', {
        width:200, 
        height:300,
        html: "hello world",
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

});
```

`this.callParent([config]);` it means call the parent with parameter config or this scope..
so, `onRender` function in `Ext.component` is overwritten by your `onRender`...

Comment: yup that was it. forgot to pass arguments in the callParent call. passing in array of config works as well.